# Failed to ensure app sand-boxed folder on external sd card with marshmallow devices

Tags: android, facebook

Android documentation says :-
Every Android app runs in a limited-access sandbox. If an app needs to use resources or information outside of its own sandbox, the app has to request the appropriate permission.

If app uses its own limited access sandbox however it may be on internal storage or on external storage. It can access sandbox folder.

It works many time but sometimes I have seen that it doesn't work, I am not sure whether its bug or something else.

```
05-05 15:48:51.832 W/ContextImpl(18430): Failed to ensure /storage/7B5C-1A0D/Android/data/com.facebook.appmanager/files/Download: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid mkdirs path: /storage/7B5C-1A0D/Android/data/com.facebook.appmanager/files/Download
05-05 15:48:51.942 D/EnterpriseController( 3149): netId is 0
05-05 15:48:51.942 D/Netd    ( 3149): getNetworkForDns: using netid 502 for uid 10095
05-05 15:48:52.672 W/ContextImpl(18430): Failed to ensure /storage/7B5C-1A0D/Android/data/com.facebook.appmanager/files/Download: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid mkdirs path: /storage/7B5C-1A0D/Android/data/com.facebook.appmanager/files/Download
```

It gives error "Failed to ensure /storage/7B5C-1A0D/Android/data/com.facebook.appmanager/files/Download"

Looks like even app accessing its own sandboxed folder need to get permission. Not sure what is happening.

I am samsung S7 Model - SM-G930FD  Android version - 6.0.1 build 1st April 2016

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. In this case, it would include the code that you are executing that is triggering those warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found that its bug in Samsung S7 Marshmallow Android version - 6.0.1 build 1st April 2016

When SD card mounts, It sends intent with following details

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED dat=file:///storage/5663-DC48 flg=0x4000010 cmp=com.bluechipsys.itraffic.hcm/.CardReceiver bqHint=4 VirtualScreenParam=Params{mDisplayId=-1, null, mFlags=0x00000000)} (has extras) }
```

This intent has mount path file:///storage/5663-DC48

When apps try to call system API for to get app sandboxed folder

```
    File fileList2[] = testService.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDirs(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

it gets following "Failed to ensure" error

```
com.techsys.test.hcm W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure /storage/A792-4DD8/Android/data/com.bluechipsys.itraffic.hcm/files/Download: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid mkdirs path: /storage/A792-4DD8/Android/data/com.techsys.test/files/Download
```

new sd card mount path is /storage/5663-DC48 but still getExternalFilesDirs is accessing old path which is /storage/A792-4DD8

may be future release will have this fix